# Passing arguments differently, function should still output the same value

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

Is there any way that I can write the function so that when I call it even by passing arguments differently, it still outputs the same value

I am new to JavaScript and was recently asked this question in an interview -

> Write a function sum which when called like sum(2)(3) or sum(2, 3) should return 5.

This could be done individually as follows

```
function sum(a){
  return function(b){
    return a+b
  }
}
```

or

```
function sum(a, b){
  return a+b
}
```

If I follow the first code, it won't execute sum(a, b) and of course the second code will not support sum(a)(b). Is there any way that I can merge the two code snippets so that it executes doesn't matter how I call it ?

Comment: Test the number of arguments you received/whether `b` is not `undefined`, and return either the sum or the function…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check how many arguments were passed. If two are passed, return the added values; otherwise, return a function that, when called, returns its argument plus the closure's argument:

```js
const sum = (...args) => {
  if (args.length === 2) {
    return args[0] + args[1];
  }
  return arg => arg + args[0];
};

console.log(sum(2)(3));
console.log(sum(2, 3));
```

More generally, you can create a `makeSum` function to handle when the total number of arguments to accept is an arbitrary number:

```js
const makeSum = totalArgCount => {
  const fn = (...args) => {
    if (args.length === totalArgCount) {
      return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
    return fn.bind(undefined, ...args);
  };
  return fn;
};

const sum2 = makeSum(2);
console.log(sum2(2)(3));
console.log(sum2(2, 3));

const sum4 = makeSum(4);
console.log(sum4(2)(3)(4)(5));
console.log(sum4(2, 3, 4)(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return b !== undefined ? (a + b) : function(b) { return a + b; }
}

console.log(sum(1,2));
console.log(sum(1)(3));
```

You can do it like this, by checking the `b` argument. If it is `undefined`, then you return a function. If it is not, you return the sum of the numbers.

Of course you could also check the both arguments are numbers, but this is simple version to illustrate what you want.